# How to know whether I need to pay tax?

Tags: taxes, india

In India, how to know whether an adult needs to pay any type of tax or not?

Is there any government source or any other way to know about it?

Answer (score 3):

The [income tax site](https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/pages/Individual-specific-content.aspx) would give you details. Broadly if your income is above RS 5 lacs you need to pay tax.